# Excel vba count last row source file

Tags: vba, row

I am relatively new to VBA.

I have a target workbook where the first step is somebody has to write something. If not an error message pops up.

After they filled in their data the code will ask them to open the source workbook(they downloaded the file before). From the source workbook certain columns are read. This all works fine in the code. The problem I have is to get what they filled in the target workbook to be copied down in column (A4:A(last row in source workbook). So the length until where their manually entered data has to be copied down has to be equal to the length of data in the source workbook.

```
Sub get_rate_codes()
Dim CheckCell As Range
Dim wb_source As Workbook
Dim wb_target As Workbook
Dim strPathName As String
Dim lastRow As Long

    For Each CheckCell In Sheets("rate_codes").Range("F3").Cells
        If Len(Trim(CheckCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            CheckCell.Select
            MsgBox "Cell " & CheckCell.Address(0, 0) & " is empty. Please enter SITA."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next CheckCell

'start to open file
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'start is the starting cell while lastRow measures the last data row in the external file
Start = 4

'continue to copy data from the rate codes report
Set wb_target = ActiveWorkbook
With wb_target.Sheets("rate_codes")
    lastRow = wb_source.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    strPathName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If strPathName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open(strPathName, 0)
    .Range("B" & Start & ":B1000").Value = wb_source.Sheets(1).Range("E2:E1000").Value
    .Range("C" & Start & ":C1000").Value = wb_source.Sheets(1).Range("H2:H1000").Value
    .Range("D" & Start & ":D1000").Value = wb_source.Sheets(1).Range("G2:G1000").Value
    .Range("E" & Start & ":E1000").Value = wb_source.Sheets(1).Range("K2:K1000").Value
    .Range("A" & Start & ":A" & lastRow).Value = wb_target.Sheets(2).Range("F2").Value         '
    wb_source.Close (False)
End With

'close file without saving
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the last row you can do this.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = wb_source.Cells(wb_source.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then you can write to the next line.

```
.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value =
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your advice but it does not seem to work. I get a run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Set wb_target = ActiveWorkbook
With wb_target.Sheets("rate_codes")
    lastRow = wb_source.Cells(wb_source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    strPathName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If strPathName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Comment: Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open(strPathName, 0)
    .Range("B" & Start & ":B1000").Value = wb_source.Sheets(1).Range("E2:E1000").Value
    .Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = wb_target.Sheets(2).Range("F2").Value         
    wb_source.Close (False)
End With